# Provability in ZFC + Con(ZFC)

Tags: logic

Let $\phi$ be a ZFC formula and $\lceil \phi \rceil$ its syntactic representation.

We can build the following program:

- program BoundedCons( x )

  - check if there exists a ZFC proof $\Gamma$ of length $|\Gamma| <= |x|$
     of a contradiction (i.e. check for a string $\lceil ZFC \vdash ... \vdash \phi \land \neg \phi \rceil$ shorter than $|x|$)
  - if we find it then *Loop forever*; otherwise *Halt*

If we define $\psi \equiv $"BoundedCons halts on all inputs"

ZFC cannot prove $\psi$, but

> Can we say that $ZFC$ augmented with an axiom that $ZFC$ is consistent proves $\psi$ (i.e. $ZFC+Con(ZFC) \vdash \psi$) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (assuming you define "length" properly) - $\psi$ is in fact equivalent to $Con(ZFC)$. More precisely, ZFC (or much, much less) proves $\psi\iff Con(ZFC))$; all we need to prove the equivalence is basic reasoning about Turing machines and proofs, and ZFC is more than enough to prove the required results.